# Error while reading file?

Tags: java, file

I am working on a project for java and I want the comiler to differentiate between number and words, but when I try the code as is, it returns error due to string of -1. Also, how do I make the number I am reading in into * symbols in a graph? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Orville’s Acres, 114.8  43801

Hoffman’s Hills, 77.2  36229

Jiffy Quick Farm,       89.4  24812

Jolly Good Plantation,  183.2  104570

Organically Grown Inc., 45.5        14683
(What I am reading in)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class Popcorn { 


  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException { 


            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String filename = f.getName();

            Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader( filename)); 
            String line = "" ; 
            while (infile.hasNextLine())
            {  line= infile.nextLine(); 

             // int endingIndex =line.indexOf(','); 
            //String fromName = line.substring(0, endingIndex);

              System.out.println(line);}
    infile.close(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error message/stack trace?

Comment: can you include what you are reading in? Not sure what you mean by differentiate between number and words and the *

Comment: Why not use a BufferedReader to parse the file and split by ','? Scanners tend to cause many people grief with InputMismatch exceptions often.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt()` to know if its a number. Have a `catch` exception block and if it comes in catch block, you'd know its not a number

Comment: It is generally not good practice to use try catch blocks for this purpose. Rather something like Character.isDigit(...) would be more appropriate.